# Like button and like counter resets to old value after scrolling up and down in listview

Tags: android, baseadapter, notifydatasetchanged

After liking a news item the heart button shows red and counter sets to 1 but after scrolling up and down the counter goes back to zero and the heart button changes from red to ash as loaded from server. I tried using notifyDataSetChanged() but didn't work in the adapter ....below is the code i implemented.

```
public class ListViewAdapterSup extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();



public ListViewAdapterSup(Context context,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}



@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    // Declare Variables
    TextView supmessageTV;
    ImageView ImageLike;
    ImageView ImageComment;
}

ViewHolder holder;



public View getView(final int position, View itemView, ViewGroup parent)     {
    itemView = null;

    if (itemView == null) {

        //itemView.setTag();
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sups_list_item, parent, false);
    // Get the position
    resultp = data.get(position);
    holder = new ViewHolder();

    // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
    holder.messageTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
    // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
    holder.ImageLike = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.likeImage);
    holder.ImageComment = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageComment);

    holder.viewLikesImageClick = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageVieew);

    }

     else{

         holder = (ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();
     }




    // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
    holder.messageTV.setText(resultp.get(News.MESSAGE));
    holder.likesCountTV.setText(resultp.get(News.LIKES_COUNT));
    holder.commentsCountTV.setText(resultp.get(News.COMMENTS_COUNT));



            holder.ImageLike.setTag(holder);
            holder.ImageLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

                         holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
                            resultp = data.get(position);

                            if(holder.ImageLike.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_24dp).getConstantState())){
                            resultp = data.get(position);

                                ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(context);
                                if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

                                    Toast.makeText(context,"No internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                    }
                                else
                                {

                                new LikeNews().execute();
                                String number = holder.likesCountTV.getText().toString();
                                int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
                                int nene = num + 1;
                                String str = String.valueOf(nene);

                                holder.likesCountTV.setText(str);   

                                //holder.likeBTN.setText("LIKED");
                                holder.ImageLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_red_24dp);

                                }

                        }

                            else if(holder.ImageLike.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite_red_24dp).getConstantState())){
                                resultp = data.get(position);

                                    ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(context);
                                    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

                                        Toast.makeText(context,"No internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                        }
                                    else
                                    {

                                    new UnLikeNews().execute();
                                    String number = holder.likesCountTV.getText().toString();
                                    int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
                                    int nene = num - 1;
                                    String str = String.valueOf(nene);

                                    holder.likesCountTV.setText(str);   

                                  //  holder.likeBTN.setText("Like");
                                    holder.ImageLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_24dp);

                                    }
                                }

                        }

                           else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {  

                               holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
                                resultp = data.get(position);

                                if(holder.ImageLike.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(holder.ImageLike.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_24dp).getConstantState())){
                                resultp = data.get(position);

                                    ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(context);
                                    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

                                        Toast.makeText(context,"No internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                        }
                                    else
                                    {

                                    new LikeNews().execute();
                                    String number = holder.likesCountTV.getText().toString();
                                    int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
                                    int nene = num + 1;
                                    String str = String.valueOf(nene);

                                    holder.likesCountTV.setText(str);   

                                    holder.ImageLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_red_24dp);

                                    }

                            }

                                else if(holder.ImageLike.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(holder.ImageLike.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite_red_24dp).getConstantState())){
                                    resultp = data.get(position);

                                        ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(context);
                                        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

                                            Toast.makeText(context,"No internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                            }
                                        else
                                        {

                                        new UnLikeNews().execute();
                                        String number = holder.likesCountTV.getText().toString();
                                        int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
                                        int nene = num - 1;
                                        String str = String.valueOf(nene);

                                        holder.likesCountTV.setText(str);   

                                        holder.ImageLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_24dp);

                                        }
                                    }

                            }



                }
            });


    return itemView;
}


public class LikeNews extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    boolean hasUserLiked = false; 

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("www.example.com");


            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "01"));
                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user));
                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_involved", "mark");

                   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                   httpclient.execute(httppost);

                   hasUserLiked = true; 

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String lenghtOfFile) {



    }

} 

public class UnLikeNews extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("www.example.com");


        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "01"));
               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user));

               httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
               httpclient.execute(httppost);



    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String lenghtOfFile) {

//       


}


} 




}
```

Answer (score 1):

`resultp = data.get(position);` should be outside of if else loop.

Comment: you are not updating data ArrayList of HashMap after LikeNews onPostExecution. set new counter value to resultp LIKES_COUNT and call  notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: Hello Giteeka am not getting you well can you please help with some code

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the ViewHolder pattern.

Call `setTag` on your `itemView`, passing in `viewHolder` **after** setting up your holder items. See last line before closing brace here:

```
if (itemView == null) {

        //itemView.setTag();
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sups_list_item, parent, false);
    // Get the position
    resultp = data.get(position);
    holder = new ViewHolder();

    // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
    holder.messageTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
    // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
    holder.ImageLike = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.likeImage);
    holder.ImageComment = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageComment);

    holder.viewLikesImageClick = (ImageView)     itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageVieew);

    itemView.setTag(holder);

}
```

This means when you get to the line

```
holder = (ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();
```

`getTag` will return the `holder` object you set as the tag, so it can properly recycle the `View` when the `View` is not null.

You should also update your `getItem` in the adapter to return the correct object.

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}
```